# Rotate Sphere x Axis Based on Mouse Position in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I have a sphere with an earth texture on it using three.js. Although the earth rotates on the y axis on it's own (horizontally), I'm not sure how to rotate the sphere on its vertical x axis based on the mouse position. The earth should show the north pole when the mouse is positioned at the top of the browser window, and the south pole when the mouse is positioned at the bottom of the screen. It should rotate to show the earth between the poles based on the vertical mouse position as the mouse moves vertically within the browser window.

How can this type of rotation be accomplished?

This code sets up the three.js scene, but the math for the rotation is not quite correct:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Earth Rotation</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var geometry   = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 100, 100);
            var material  = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
            var earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

            material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/earth.jpg');

            var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc );
            scene.add(light);
            scene.add(earthMesh);

            camera.position.z = 1.5;

            document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
                if(event.clientY < window.innerHeight / 2) {
                    earthMesh.rotation.x = ((window.innerHeight / 2) - (event.clientY * .0001));
                } else if(event.clientY > window.innerHeight / 2) {
                    earthMesh.rotation.x = ((window.innerHeight / 2) + (event.clientY * .0001));
                }
            }, false)

            var animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                earthMesh.rotation.y -= 0.0005;
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it an option to move the camera over the globe instead of rotating the globe?

Comment: Of course, I just thought it would be easier to rotate the globe. When moving the camera, I couldn't figure out how to give it more of an orbit trajectory, instead of just moving it along an axis. Simply moving it along a vertical axis results in a greater distance created between the earth and the camera.

Comment: Why not use `THREE.OrbitControls()` then?

Comment: Is it possible to use THREE.OrbitControls() with a movemove event isn't of clicking and dragging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, you can achieve the same thing, using `THREE.OrbtiControls()` with some modifications.

Just an option with moving the camera over the rotating globe.

r96

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 10;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var globe = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(4, 32, 16), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2521/3884071286_edb50f8137_b.jpg")
}));
scene.add(globe);

window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);

function onMouseMove(event) {
  camera.position.setFromSphericalCoords(10, Math.PI * -event.clientY / window.innerHeight, 0);
  camera.lookAt(globe.position);
}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  globe.rotation.y -= 0.005;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
```